AWS SAM request mapping to retrieve the raw request body of a Stripe webhook returning undefined
I've created a web app and looking to integrate Stripe for subscriptions to premium features of the web app.
Using AWS SAM I've tried the below Body Mapping Template in the snippet of my template.yaml per Stripe's documentation to retrieve the raw request body from Stripe and the Lambda function below is returning undefined for rawBody but headers has a value.
What am I missing or doing wrong? I've scoured stack overflow and the internet for answers with no luck. I'd appreciate any advice/direction.
snippet of template.yaml
  ApiGatewayRestApi:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      Name: xxxxx
      Description: xxxxx
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Types:
          - REGIONAL

  ApiGatewayDeployment:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
    DependsOn:
      - StripeWebhookMethod
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayRestApi
      StageName: Prod

  StripeWebhookResource:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
    Properties:
      ParentId: !GetAtt ApiGatewayRestApi.RootResourceId
      PathPart: stripe-webhook
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayRestApi

  StripeWebhookMethod:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      HttpMethod: POST
      ResourceId: !Ref StripeWebhookResource
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayRestApi
      Integration:
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        Type: AWS_PROXY
        Uri: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${stripeWebhookFunction.Arn}/invocations
        RequestTemplates:
          application/json: |
            {
              "method": "$context.httpMethod",
              "body": $input.json('$'),
              "rawBody": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.body).replaceAll("\\'", "'")",
              "headers": {
                #foreach($param in $input.params().header.keySet())
                "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().header.get($param))"
                #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
                #end
              }
            }
        IntegrationResponses:
          - StatusCode: 200
            ResponseTemplates:
              application/json: "{}"
      MethodResponses:
        - StatusCode: 200

Lambda function
import { PutCommand, QueryCommand } from "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb";
import { getClient, formatResponse } from "../utils.mjs";
import stripePackage from "stripe";

const stripe = stripePackage(process.env.STRIPE_API_KEY);
const ddbDocClient = getClient();
const tableName = process.env.APP_TABLE;
const appVersion = process.env.APP_VERSION;

export const stripeWebhookHandler = async (event) => {
  const { rawBody, headers } = event;
  const signature = headers["Stripe-Signature"];
  const webhookSecret = process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET;

  console.log("rawBody: ", rawBody);
  console.log("headers: ", headers);
  console.log("signature: ", signature);

  let stripeEvent;

  // Verify Stripe event is legit
  try {
    stripeEvent = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
      rawBody,
      signature,
      webhookSecret,
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Webhook signature verification failed. ${err.message}`);
    return formatResponse(400, { error: err.message });
  }

  const { data, type: eventType } = stripeEvent;

  try {
    switch (eventType) {
      case "checkout.session.completed":
        await handleCheckoutSessionCompleted(data);
        break;

      case "customer.subscription.deleted":
        await handleCustomerSubscriptionDeleted(data);
        break;

      default:
        console.warn(`Unhandled event type: ${eventType}`);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(`Stripe error: ${e.message} | EVENT TYPE: ${eventType}`);
  }

  return formatResponse(200, {});
};

const handleCheckoutSessionCompleted = async (data) => {
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(data.object.id, {
    expand: ["line_items"],
  });
  const customerId = session.customer;
  const customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(customerId);
  const priceId = session.line_items.data[0].price.id;

  if (!customer.email) {
    console.error("No user found");
    throw new Error("No user found");
  }

  const userParams = {
    TableName: tableName,
    IndexName: "GSI1",
    KeyConditionExpression: "GSI1PK = :email",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":email": `USER#${appVersion}#EMAIL#${customer.email}#`,
    },
  };

  const result = await ddbDocClient
    .send(new QueryCommand(userParams))
    .promise();

  const userItem =
    result.Items.length > 0
      ? result.Items[0]
      : {
          PK: `FU#${appVersion}#${customer.email}#`,
          SK: "PROFILE",
          GSI1PK: `USER#${appVersion}#EMAIL#${customer.email}`,
          GSI1SK: `USER#${appVersion}#${customer.email}`,
          email: customer.email,
          name: customer.name,
          customerId,
          priceId,
          hasAccess: true,
        };

  if (result.Items.length > 0) {
    userItem.customerId = customerId;
    userItem.priceId = priceId;
    userItem.hasAccess = true;
  }

  await ddbDocClient.send(
    new PutCommand({ TableName: tableName, Item: userItem }),
  );
};

const handleCustomerSubscriptionDeleted = async (data) => {
  const customerId = data.object.customer;
  const customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(customerId);

  if (!customer.email) {
    console.error("No user found");
    throw new Error("No user found");
  }

  const userParams = {
    TableName: tableName,
    IndexName: "GSI1",
    KeyConditionExpression: "GSI1PK = :email",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":email": `USER#${appVersion}#EMAIL#${customer.email}#`,
    },
  };

  const result = await ddbDocClient
    .send(new QueryCommand(userParams))
    .promise();

  if (result.Items.length > 0) {
    const userItem = result.Items[0];
    userItem.hasAccess = false;

    await ddbDocClient.send(
      new PutCommand({ TableName: tableName, Item: userItem }),
    );
  } else {
    console.warn(`User with email ${customer.email} not found.`);
  }
};


